# ng-grid does not work with file-referenced cell template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using `angular-js` + [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#/examples) and for some columns I want to use cell-templates. But for some reason it doesn't want to work when template-html is stored and referenced as a file.

```
    columnDefs: [ { 
       field: "Foo", 
       displayName: "Foo", 
       cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity[col.field]"/> </div>' 
    }] // OK

    columnDefs: [ { field: "Foo", displayName: "Foo", cellTemplate: 'cellTemplate.html' } ]
    // Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error
```

Moreover, if I follow a link to [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iv50t3OpzpUvcGrz9Zkp?p=info) from their site I see that it doesn't work as well.  ( you can follow the link to see the exact error text ).

Comment: corrected link to plunkr.  ( http://plnkr.co/edit/iv50t3OpzpUvcGrz9Zkp?p=info )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work if you give the external template another name than the one that is already in the `$templateCache`.

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
        field: 'age',
        displayName: 'Age',
        cellTemplate: "exCellTemplate.html"
    }]
    };
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4hUlnvAfDo86MIRoUda?p=preview)